# How can i include my template from the static folder in django

Tags: python, django

I have the djnago app structure like

`myproject/myapp`

`myproject/myapp/static/site/app/index.html`

I want to include that template in my file like this

`url(r'^public$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="/static/site/app/index.html")),`

but it says template not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import os
 import sys

 PORJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')
 sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'))
```

Comment: It is PROJECT_ROOT not PORJECT_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder is included in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting (in settings.py).

Comment: how can i hard code the path there. like `myproject.static` or something else

Comment: Hard code? Sorry, i don't understand what you want to do. First, there's an error on `template_name`. It should be "static/site/app/index.html", instead of "/static/site/app/index.html", because it is interpreted as a relativa path from other path explicited in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. So, add the absolute path holding the folder static (e: "C:/myprject/myapp/" or "/home/django/myproject/myapp/").

Answer (score 0):

Generally(by convention) template files folder is project_root_folder\templates folder, update TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py:

```
import os
PORJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PORJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

While static store only javascript/css/images fiels.

That will make future develop and deploy easier.

Answer (score 0):

BY default django checks in app/templates directory for a template match, or in the project_root/templates/. You should have the directory listed in the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting as others have stated.